# How to calculate a definite integral using Taylor series expansion

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the value of $A$ from the following integral:
$$
\int_0^∞ A^2x^4 e^{-2αx} dx=1
$$
where $α$ is a positive number. Using integration by parts, I get:
$$
\int_0^∞ A^2x^4 e^{-2αx} dx= A^2\left[e^{-2αx} \left(-\frac{x^4}{2α}-\frac{x^3}{α^2}-\frac{3x^2}{2α^3}-\frac{3x}{2α^4}-\frac{3}{4α^5}\right)\right]_0^∞
$$
The result I'm looking for is:
$$
A=\sqrt\frac{4α^5}{3}
$$
Which I know can be obtained by rearranging the following (found from the integral):
$$
A^2\frac{3}{4α^5}=1
$$
And I'm sure that this is done using a Taylor expansion, but I can't quite understand how to get that result. I don't see a way to sub infinity into the equation I got from using integration by parts. I understand that $e^{-2αx}$ is essentially $0$ as $x\to∞$. This is where I'm struggling, the $\frac{A^23}{4α^5}$ term is present in the result I get from integration by parts, but where do all of the other terms go? Why are they discarded? I don't understand the Taylor expansion at all.

Comment: You don’t need to plug in $\infty$. Treat it like a limit and apply l’Hospital’s rule. Everything falls out from there, you don’t need Taylor series ar all

Comment: Look at what happens at $0$ and $\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand how the other terms vanish, let's examine the generic term

$e^{-ax}\cdot bx^c$, where $a,c>0$, as $x\to0$ and $x\to\infty$.

$\underline{\text{Case I: }x\to0}$

It is trivial. Plugging in $x=0$, we have $e^{-ax}\cdot bx^c=e^0\cdot b\cdot0^c=0$.

$\underline{\text{Case II: }x\to\infty}$

Plugging in $x=\infty$, we have $e^{-ax}\cdot bx^c=e^{-\infty}\cdot b\cdot\infty^c=0\times\infty$, which is an indeterminate form.

To figure out this limit, we may make use of L'Hopital's rule.

$\lim_{x\to k}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to k}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},\ \ \ $ if $f(x),g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to k$.

Then,

$\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-ax}\cdot bx^c$

$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{bx^c}{e^{ax}}$ (denominator and numerator go to infinity so we can apply L'Hopital's rule here)

$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{bcx^{c-1}}{ae^{ax}}$ (both sides still go to infinity. Repeat.)

$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{bc(c-1)x^{c-2}}{a^2e^{ax}}$ ($e^{ax}$ remains untouched and $x^c$ is slowly eroding. Let's repeat until $x^c$ is eaten up.)

$\vdots\\
=
\begin{cases}
\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{bc!}{a^ce^{ax}}\ \text{ if }c\in\mathbb{Z}\\ \\
\lim_{x\to\infty}\dfrac{bc(c-1)\ldots(c-\lfloor c\rfloor)}{a^{\lceil c\rceil}x^{1-(c-\lfloor c\rfloor)}e^{ax}}\ \text{ if }c\notin\mathbb{Z}
\end{cases}$

$= 0$

In both cases I & II, the term goes to zero as $x\to 0$ or $x\to\infty$. Therefore, all the terms in the form of a product of (1) $x$ raised to a positive power, and (2) $e$ raised to a negative power disappear.

In verbal terms, the result means that in $e^{-ax}\cdot bx^c$,

$e^{-ax}$ goes to $0$ "faster" than $x^c$ grows to $\infty$.

Comment: This explained it perfectly and I think I understand now, thank you for taking the time to write such a detailed response! :)